# Не работает метод messages.getHistory VK API. Как получить полную историю сообщений?

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Хочу получить историю сообщений при помощи метода messages.getHistory из VK API.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getHistory?user_id=" + id + "&offset=" + m + "&count=200&access_token=" + token);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();

responseFromServer = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseFromServer);//возвращает "{\"response\":[0]}"
JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
messagesList = token["response"].Children().Skip(1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Friend>()).ToList();
```

Но в ответе от сервера всегда пусто: "{\"response\":[0]}"
Пробовал метод messages.get и он работает. Но мне нужна полная история сообщений.
Кто-то знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А чего не пользуетесь библиотечкой официальной? https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-windowsphone-sdk

Comment: @pavelip, вы когда-нибудь ей пользовались? )) Хотя да, `vk.net` ещё более отвратительно сделан.

Comment: Не пользовался. А в чем проблема? Она не работает?

Comment: У vk.net много методов криво работает. vk-windowsphone-sdk не пробовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я посылал свой id, и думал, что сервер вернет мне историю сообщений. А оказывается надо было посылать id конкретного пользователя, с которым у тебя есть сообщение. А чтоб получить список всех переписок надо использовать метод [messages.getDialogs](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getDialogs).